# High privileges needed: warn or kill when not given?

Tags: c, linux

After I find out whether the program is running as root or normal user, and knowing that this program must run with high privileges, I'm wondering if I should keep running although the program will surely fail or exit directly?
Which option and why you think is better?

Thanks and have a nice day.

**Are you still confuse?**
Summing up: you've got a program that needs high privileges to run. You check through a system call if it is running as root or non-root. Then you find out it does not have the privileges that it needs to run correctly; what would you do? You would exit (returning 1 e.g) or keep going on and warn the user?

Comment: Can't understand why it's unclear. I'm going to make it even easier, even though it is already.

Comment: I don't see how this can be considered unclear.  I beleive 2 people understood it well enough to answer before it was lcosed and both took the same meaning,

Comment: It may not be unclear, but it is asking for opinions about what the best behavior is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know you'll fail, it's better to write a clear message to the user and exit normally before your app crashes.

Answer (score 1):

If it can't do what is meant probably exit.

If it does damage running by not completing because of this certainly exit.

If if does most stuff without root consider a config option to control this.

If it exits as I try to start it I will know and if there is a meaningful error message fix it (you do write a log file, right? :))